# Virus alert when opening mse questions

Tags: support

Every time I've opened an mse question today my virus checker has put up an alert from
http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/wmd.js?v=4299f69ea585.
Yesterday all was fine.
I understand that cdn is some technology used by all the SE sites.
Has anyone else seen this? Is there anything I can do? It's very annoying.

**Edit 1** I am using Avira version 12. The screen shot in the mso post in Willie's answer is exactly what I get.
**Edit 2** I have updated my Avira virus files and rebooted, and the alerts have gone away on the mse posts (which sounds like end of problem) but I still get the alerts opening mso posts. I think I'll wait for Avira to sort themselves out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send a feedback to the vendor of your antivirus software, since it is likely a false positive.

[Here's a related discussion at Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111351/virus-reported-after-loading-page).

Comment: Thankyou Willie